# Xpath - how to extract data using class target

Tags: xpath

Code snippet:

```
<td class="right odds down"><a class=" betslip" target="unibet" onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','24vekxv464x0x4g25d',5,event,1,1)" href="/bookmaker/unibet/betslip//event/1002752206/coupon/single,2133228960,p,[0]">1.70</a></td>
```

I trying to extract data from a page where the class target is "Unibet".
What would be the correct formatting for this query?

Ive tried:

> //*[classtarget="unibet"]//td/a/@class

Comment: `//a[@target="unibet"]/@class`

Answer (score 0):

Well, `target` is *attribute*, not class, of element `<a>`. The XPath to find `<td>` element and then return the child element `<a>` where `target` attribute value equals `"unibet"` will be :

```
//td/a[@target='unibet']
```

if you want to return `class` attribute of the `<a>` element instead, simply add a trailing `/@class` to the above XPath :

```
//td/a[@target='unibet']/@class
```